# Is there a possibility to automatically login by clicking on verify email link triggered by /send-verify-email

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

If Keycloak's self-registration form is used, once submitted, it will send an email verification link to that newly registered user.
Once the user clicks the link, his email will be verified, and it will redirect him to the `redirectUri` from his client and provide the authorization code, which is perfect.

The problem arises when I don't want to use Keycloak's registration form, instead I have a custom registration mobile form, which sends the user data. Those data is then sent to the Keycloak by Admin REST create user API.
Once the user is created, by triggering `/send-verify-email` or `/execute-actions-email` APIs none of them are returning authorization code in the end. Yes, they do redirect to the redirectUri which you specified, but I need authorization code as well, in order to be logged in automatically upon clicking on the link.